# how to send multiple values with multiple select input

Tags: php, html

I need to know which will be better to insert multiple values into table with multiple select input with also more than one value.

Is better with one value sepparated with "|" each value or is better with data-id, date-price, etc?

Here the input with the first form:

```
<select class="form-control form-control-lg" name="toBuy[]" id="multi" multiple="multiple" style="width:100%">
    <?php
        $sql = $conn->prepare("SELECT id, name, price FROM ITEMS WHERE active != 0");
        $sql->execute();
        while($row = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            echo '<option value="'.$row['name'].'|'.$row['id'].'|'.$row['price'].'">'.$row['name'].'</option>';
        }
    ?>
</select>
```

Here the input with the second form:

```
<select class="form-control form-control-lg" name="toBuy[]" id="multi" multiple="multiple" style="width:100%">
    <?php
        $sql = $conn->prepare("SELECT id, name, price FROM ITEMS WHERE active != 0");
        $sql->execute();
        while($row = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            echo '<option value="'.$row['name'].'" data-id="'.$row['id'].'" data-price="'.$row['price'].'">'.$row['name'].'</option>';
        }
    ?>
</select>
```

Now in the insert file, how can I add those value into the table?

```
        $sql2 = "INSERT INTO PAID (idItem, name, price, idUser)
         VALUES ";
        $insertQuery2 = array();
        $insertData2 = array();
        foreach ($_POST['id'] as $i => $item) {

            //WITH THE FIRST FORM
            $result = explode('|', $_POST['toBuy']);
            $result.[0];
            $result.[1];
            $result.[2];

            $insertQuery2[] = '(?, ?, ?, ?)';
            $insertData2[] = $result.[0][$i];
            $insertData2[] = $result.[1][$i];
            $insertData2[] = $result.[2][$i];
            $insertData2[] = $idUser;


            //SECOND FORM

            $insertQuery2[] = '(?, ?, ?, ?)';
            $insertData2[] = $_POST['id'][$i];
            $insertData2[] = $_POST['name'][$i];
            $insertData2[] = $_POST['price'][$i];
            $insertData2[] = $idUser;
        }
        if (!empty($insertQuery2)) {
            $sql2 .= implode(', ', $insertQuery2);
            $stmt2 = $conn->prepare($sql2);
            $stmt2->execute($insertData2);
        }
```

Comment: So you are going to get the price from the user, *seriously*? You're going to get a lot of surprises. And what's the point in storing the product name, isn't it already in the database? Don't be silly, **send only the product id**. Then get the price from database on the server

Comment: I also fail to see how your question is related to insert, as it is clearly about how to send multiple values from hrml select. But in reality you don't need multiple but only one - the product id

Comment: @YourCommonSense. mmm your are right!, thank you I will do it like you said

Answer (score 1):

You only need to use the item_id and user_id for this one. Data related to the item is already stored in your item table. What you need to do here is push all the selected item_id's into an array and use a loop when inserting values.

Comment: The price is better to be stored along with the order, as it will be changed over time.

Comment: Yeah, it's better that way. But in this scenario, he should probably just get the item_id.

Answer (score -1):

First, as mentioned before, you only need:

```
echo '<option value="'.$row['id'].'">'.$row['name'].'</option>';
```

With the multiple option you should get an array of chosen ids. Then your SQL string could be (with added sanitation):

```
$ids = filter_input(
    INPUT_POST,
    'toBuy',
    FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT,
    FILTER_REQUIRE_ARRAY
);

$data = array_merge([$idUser], $ids);
$inparams = implode(',', array_fill(0, count($ids), '?'));

$sql = "INSERT INTO PAID (idItem, name, price, idUser) ";
$sql.= "SELECT id, name, price, ? ";
$sql.= "FROM ITEMS ";
$sql.= "WHERE id IN ($inparams)";

$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute($data);
```

Voila, this should do it. Maybe there's an error in it, I coded it on the fly without testing, but maybe you get the idea.

For HTML SELECT OPTION examination and sanitation see:
https://www.phptutorial.net/php-tutorial/php-select-option/
For SQL INSERT INTO SELECT tutorial see:
https://www.w3schools.com/SQL/sql_insert_into_select.asp