# get multiple regions from checkbox at a time in a row in Mysql php

Tags: php, mysql

I am a beginner in Mysql Php. I want to get multiple regions from a table in mysql. I have alredy a script which is given below.

this is my html code:

```
<form >
   <div class="regionFiltre">
        <div class="select-box">
            <div class="options-container">
                <label class="container">16 - Alger
                    <input type="checkbox" name="region[]" value="16">
                    <span class="checkmark"></span>
                </label>
                <label class="container">31- Oran
                    <input type="checkbox" name="region[]" value="31">
                    <span class="checkmark"></span>
                </label>
                <label class="container">09 - Blida
                    <input type="checkbox" name="region[]" value="09">
                    <span class="checkmark"></span>
                    </label>
                <label class="container" >42 - Tipaza
                    <input type="checkbox" name="region[]" value="42">
                    <span class="checkmark"></span>
                </label>
                <label class="container">42 - Boumerdes
                    <input type="checkbox" name="region[]" value="35">
                    <span class="checkmark"></span>
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="selected">Wilaya</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Recherche" class="searchBtn">
</form>
```

and this is my php code (not all the code):

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['region']))
{   
    if(!empty ($_REQUEST['region']))
    {
        foreach ( $_REQUEST['region'] as $region)
        {
            $region = $_REQUEST['region'];
            $region = AntiInjectionSQL($region);
            $adderegion = " AND idregion = '$region'";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $adderegion = "";
    }

$SQL = "SELECT * FROM pas_annonce WHERE status != 'NOVISIBLE' $addregion"
    $_reponse = $pdo->query($SQL);
```

I did not put all the code but this is how i want to get region for exempl, from sql:

```
$SQL = "SELECT * FROM pas_annonce WHERE status != 'NOVISIBLE' AND idregion = '16' OR AND idregion = '09'"// i want to get a single or a multiple regions
```

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting the variable whenever it goes through a new iteration in foreach.
A correction would be:

```
$adderegion = "";
foreach ( $_REQUEST['region'] as $region)
{
    $region = $_REQUEST['region'];
    $region = AntiInjectionSQL($region);
    $adderegion .= " AND idregion = '$region'";
}
```

[See operator String documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php)

Comment: 1. There is a logical issue. It sould be the OR operator, not the AND operator. If you search for someID = x AND someID = y, you always will find nothing, because someID cant be x and y at the same time.
2. We need user input validation
3. We should use PDO prepare/execute
4. The IN operator is one of the most useful but overlooked operators in SQL.

Comment: @Aranxo. Yes, but I was careful to just solve his current problem, the other questions he will learn with time.
That could confuse his head with too much information

Comment: Yes, I did understand that, and that's the reason why I didn't downvote your answer, because I saw your aim. When answering questions here, I often live in the dilemma: Should I answer quick and focused on the presented tiny little problem, but ignore the big issues that are already present in the code, which also should be solved. Or should I setup for the big throw, explain all the things which sould be done and run the risk of overburdening the person asking for help. Well, just last week I got punished for not including all the validation, salvation and hardening stuff.

Answer (score 0):

First, never trust user input of forms. You will never know, what user actually try to send you in your `$region` array. This is one of the most common answers you will always hear. Maybe using some filters could save you much worries. Try to start here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php

If you like video tutorials, I liked this one: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pfY9LwcsH3A

Even much better is when you only allow your distinct values `(09, 16, 31, 35, 42)` in your array and filter all others out. Maybe in this way:

```
 $region = array_intersect($region, [09, 16, 31, 35, 42]);
```

Next, use placeholders like `?` or `:region`, which also prevents misusing your DB by hackers in some way. Then use the PDO prepare command to prepare the SQL statement and then the PDO execute command to fill in the parameters as an array.

One of the best PDO tutorials I remember is this one: https://phpdelusions.net/pdo

And last: Consider using the SQL IN operator. Therefore, you don't need a loop.

I answered just a few days ago a very similar question with a code example regarding to that question. It was an `INPUT INTO` SQL statement, but that's not the big difference. Important is how to use the IN operator. There you can see how to use filters, how to use the PDO prepare/execute combination and how to use the IN operator and prepare some placeholders for your array:
[how to send multiple values with multiple select input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72208735/how-to-send-multiple-values-with-multiple-select-input/72209461#72209461)